# intersection of border and route in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I have a specific area of the operation (like city or town) but would like to travel from point A in that area to point B outside of that area  how can I check the exact point of the intersection of a route and border of area on google map?

ts like A -> [ C ] -> B
where A and B are start and finish point of route 
and C is exact point for route / border - so i need distance (A;C) and then distance (C;B) with information where C is (intersection of route and border)

its urgent for me,

cheers, Marcin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the total distance of a Polyline segment within a Polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405264/find-the-total-distance-of-a-polyline-segment-within-a-polygon) (although that doesn't have any accepted answers)